# I wrote some prolog logic, how do I write a script that uses it?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm writing an assignment for a prolog class and I'm stuck on something simple.  I've written a bunch of logic in a file called question1.pl

I'm using SWI on Mac OS X, so at the command prompt I do this:

```
swilg
consult('question1.pl').
```

to load the file, then to test it I do:

```
?- father(homer,bart).
true
?- father(marge,bart).
false
```

and so on.

My question is, how do I write a "test script" for my code?

I'm assuming I should write something like question1-tests.pl that looks like this:

```
(write 'test1, should be true').
father(homer,bart).
(write 'test2, should be false').
father(marge,bart).
```

But how do I run that script?

Sorry, I know this is simple, but I'm stuck.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you can make a script like this:

```
swipl <<END
[question1].
write('test1, should be true').
father(homer,bart).
write('test2, should be false').
father(marge,bart).
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I figured out I can add this to my question1.pl ...

```
doTests:-write('Test1, should be true'),nl,father(homer,bart).
```

And simply run

```
?- doTests
```

To get output.  Sufficient for my assignment needs.